# Merging a dict class attribute through the class hierarchy

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, inheritance, dictionary

I'm trying to make the following code work. I'd like to create a class attribute which is a dictionary of default values that automatically updates from children to parents through the class hierarchy. Ideally I'd like to do it with magic in the parent object so that child objects can simply override values as needed. I'd also be open to suggestions for how to redesign this if there's an idiom for this kind of thing.

```
class A(object):
  DEFAULTS = {'a': 'default a', 'd': 'test d'}

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
    # but can i do something with super? this fails but is the
    # approximate idea of what I want...
    # self.DEFAULTS.update(super(self.__class__, self).DEFAULTS)

class B(A):
  DEFAULTS = {'b': 'default b'}

class C(A):
  DEFAULTS = {'a': 'a overridden in C'}

class D(C):
  DEFAULTS = {'d': 'd overridden in D'}

def test():
  a = A()
  b = B()
  c = C()
  d = D()
  print a.DEFAULTS
  print b.DEFAULTS
  print c.DEFAULTS
  print d.DEFAULTS
  assert (a.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'default a', 'd': 'test d'})
  assert (b.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'default a', 'b': 'default b', 'd': 'test d'})
  assert (c.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'overridden in c', 'd': 'test d'})
  assert (d.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'overridden in c', 'd': 'd overridden in D'})

test()
```

Of course right now this results in the following output:

```
{'a': 'default a', 'd': 'test d'}
{'b': 'default b'}
{'a': 'a overridden in C'}
{'d': 'd overridden in D'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experimental/users/edw/python/class_magic.py", line 36, in <module>
    test()
  File "experimental/users/edw/python/class_magic.py", line 32, in test
    assert (b.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'default a', 'b': 'default b', 'd': 'test d'})
AssertionError
```

Comment: You can't really do that with class attributes, except by using metaclasses which is probably overkill. You could make them instance attributes, or even properties.

Comment: Without explicitly calling dict.update along the way there is no way you can do what you want

Comment: I'm restricted to using class attributes unless I go rewrite a bunch of the surrounding code. Our current solution is just to re-set values in subclasses manually which is okay but amounts to copy/paste which I don't love. I'd be interested in a metaclass example, metaclasses are deeper magic than I've used.

Comment: @padraic-cunningham i'm fine calling update in class A in the example above but really trying to avoid calling it in subclasses thereof.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [sobolevn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4842742/sobolevn) for the metaclass example. I built on that to move the defaults inside the child classes rather than a single external data structure like the example in the original question. Performance might be an issue if the dictionary being copied grows large but since this is code as config that would be unexpected in practice.

```
class DefaultsMetaBase(type):
  """Automatically merges DEFAULTS from all parent classes."""
  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = type.__call__(self)
    for klass in obj.__class__.__mro__:
      if klass == obj.__class__ or klass == Base or not issubclass(klass, Base):
        continue
      if hasattr(klass, 'DEFAULTS'):
        d = klass.DEFAULTS.copy()
        d.update(obj.DEFAULTS)
        obj.DEFAULTS = d
    return obj

class Base(object):
  __metaclass__ = DefaultsMetaBase

class A(Base):
  DEFAULTS = {'a': 'default a', 'd': 'test d'}

class B(A):
  DEFAULTS = {'b': 'default b'}

class C(A):
  DEFAULTS = {'a': 'a overridden in C'}
  some_setting = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

class D(C):
  DEFAULTS = {'d': 'd overridden in D'}
  some_setting = ['q', 'r', 's']
  another_setting = 'moar roar'

class F(D):
  another_setting = 'less roar'

def test():
  a = A()
  b = B()
  c = C()
  d = D()
  f = F()
  assert (a.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'default a', 'd': 'test d'})
  assert (b.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'default a', 'b': 'default b', 'd': 'test d'})
  assert (c.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'a overridden in C', 'd': 'test d'})
  assert (d.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'a overridden in C', 'd': 'd overridden in D'})
  assert (f.DEFAULTS == {'a': 'a overridden in C', 'd': 'd overridden in D'})
  print 'pass!'

test()
```

Comment: If I copy past this directly it doesn't work, at least not in python 3 after converting print "pass" to print("pass").

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit your needs?

Example with methods:

```
class A(object):
    _DEFAULTS = {'a': 'a value'}

    @classmethod
    def get_defaults(cls):
        return cls._DEFAULTS

class B(A):
    _B_DEFAULTS = {'b': 'b value'}

    @classmethod
    def get_defaults(cls):
        defaults = super(B, cls).get_defaults()
        defaults.update(cls._B_DEFAULTS)
        return defaults
```

Metaclass example:

```
# Some data-structure (it should be refactored): 
_DEFAULTS = {'A': {'a': 'a_value'}, 'B': {'b': 'b_value'}}

class DefaultsInitializer(type):
     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          obj = type.__call__(self)
          obj.defaults = _DEFAULTS[obj.__class__.__name__]
          for klass in obj.__class__.__bases__:
               if klass.__name__ in _DEFAULTS:
                    obj.defaults.update(_DEFAULTS[klass.__name__])
          return obj
```

And some classes:

```
>>> class A(object):
...      __metaclass__ = DefaultsInitializer
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.defaults
{'a': 'a_value'}
>>> class B(A):
...      pass
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.defaults
{'a': 'a_value', 'b': 'b_value'}
```

Comment: Thank you but no. I'm specifically trying to avoid methods like get_defaults in the subclasses.

Comment: i think the metaclass version can be retrofitted into the original question to make it work, will try this afternoon. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you want something like what happens normally with class attributes -- children inherit parent attributes and can hide parent attributes with own values if desired.

eg.

```
class A(object):
    a = 'a'

class B(A):
    b = 'b'

class C(A):
    a = 'c'

assert A.a == 'a'and A().a == 'a'
assert B.a == 'a' # B inherits a
assert C.a == 'c' # C overrides a
```

It also allows instances to override defaults

```
a = A()
a.a = 'not a'
assert A.a == 'a' and A().a == 'a'
assert a.a == 'not a'
```

However, maybe you don't want your defaults to be accessible like this. No worries. Define a defaults class on the parent and get the child to define a child defaults. eg.

```
class A(object):
    class defaults(object):
        a = 'a'

class B(A):
    class defaults(A.defaults):
        b = 'b'

class C(A):
    class defaults(A.defaults):
        a = 'c'

assert A.defaults.a == 'a' and A().defaults.a == 'a'
assert B.defaults.a == 'a' # B inherits a
assert C.defaults.a == 'c' # C overrides a
```

Or, it you really, really, want defaults to be a dict-like object then just define a dict-like object that overrides `__getitem__` and the various other methods you may care about.

```
def defaults(**kwargs):
    """decorator to add defaults to a class"""
    def default_setter(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, "defaults"):
            cls.defaults = DefaultGetter()
        for key, value in kwargs:
            setattr(cls, "_default_"+key, value)
        return cls
    return default_setter

class DefaultGetter(object):
    """dict-like object that retrieves the defaults"""
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.owner, "_default_" + name)
        except AttributeError:
            raise KeyError(name) from None

@defaults(a='a')
class A(object):
     pass

assert A.defaults['a'] == 'a'
assert A._default_a == 'a' # actual storage location of a
A.defaults['b'] # raises KeyError
```